# Python's readline() function seeming not to work?

Tags: python, file, readline

for some reason the readline() function in my following code seems to print nothing.

```
fileName = input()
    fileName += ".txt"
    fileA = open(fileName, 'a+')
    print("Opened", fileA.name)

    line = fileA.readline()
    print(line)
    fileA.close()
```

I'm using PyCharm, and I've been attempting to access 'file.txt' which is located inside my only PyCharm project folder. It contains the following:

```
Opened file!!
```

I have no idea what is wrong, and I can't find any relevant information for my problem whatsoever. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you opened the file in `a+` mode, the file pointer starts at the end of the file. After all, that is where you would normally append text.

If you want to read from the top, you need to place [`fileA.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) just before you call `readline`:

```
fileA.seek(0)
line = fileA.readline()
```

Doing so sets the pointer to the top of the file.

---

**Note:** After reading the comments, it appears that you only need to do this if you are running a Windows machine.  Those using a *nix system should not have this problem.

Comment: That does not happen for me. I have a single line in the file and it prints the line just fine

Comment: put a `print fileA.tell()` before readline. The file is open at pos 0 for reading, if you write it will write to the end.` a+` opens the file for writing and reading.

Comment: I don't think you'd need to seek to the start on Unix-type systems. The Microsoft C runtime will remove a CTRL-Z character at the end of an existing file when you use "a+", so presumably it leaves the file pointer at the end of the file after doing so.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - `fileA.tell` gives `13` for me (the end of the file).  Are you using a *nix system?  I'm currently on a Windows machine, so this is probably a Windows-only issue.

Comment: Yep Ubuntu 14.05, must be a windoze issue! `fileA.tell` gives me `0`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Heh.  I have a friend who refuses to call Windows by any other name than "windoze".  I'll edit my answer to mention that this is a Windows-only issue.

Comment: @iCodez, I cannot do windoze, a man can only take so many reinstalls in his life! +1 Good catch anyway.